# What's wrong with this piece of java code?

Tags: java

Just looking at past exam papers and stumbled across the following question which doesn't make much sense to me:

The following piece of code is meant to greet the user in an appropriate manner:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.out.println("Enter a name");
    String name = EasyIn.getString();
    if (name == "" ) 
        System.out.println("You must input a name");
    else 
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name);
}
```

The question asks why the program may not do what the programmer intended. With a lack of a laptop at the moment (spilt drink on it!) I can't test the code with different inputs etc. From what I can tell, the only problem with it is that it doesn't ask the user for another input of name if it is blank, and just terminates the program. I'd use this as the answer, but it is brought up later on in the question directly which makes me think it isn't the answer they're looking for. Are there any other problems with the code?

Comment: Typically you dont use `==` with reference data types like `String`

Comment: Yep, there's another HUGE problem with this code.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) may interest you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `String.equals` question, replace:

```
if (name == "" )
```

with

```
if (name.equals(""))
```

The `==` operator compares object references, You need to use `String.equals` to compare `String` content. Alternatively you could use:

```
if (name.IsEmpty())
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (name == "" )
```

to:

```
if (name.equals(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

It uses `== ""` instead of `.equals("")`, or better yet, `.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#equals()`, not `==`, for checking string equality.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is `String comparison` using `==` operator. That would not give the intended result. `==` operator compares the `String Reference` values, and not the contents.

String comparison should always be done using `equals` method, if the intention is to compare the `contents` of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should check string equality using equals() method. `==` operator in case of strings just checks if two strings refer to the same string object

```
 if (name == "" )

should be

 if (name.equals("") )
```

or you could also use [**String.isEmpty()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) to check if the string isempty

```
 if (name.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

It compares Strings with `==` instead of `.equals()`.

`==` compares object references. It doesn't compere the contents of two strings.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, that you can not do == with strings. You must use the method name.equals

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't to leave the comments. 
 1. So, what you meant when wrote that program just is terminates? I think, it should print one of two "println()" - which?
 2. Mybee you should insert something sorta loop "while", that will operate until user enters not empty string:

```
while (!name.equals("")) { ... }
```

PS. sorry, I cannot to leave the comments & I saw that there isn't any approved answer...